# find actual date according to quantity which is committed at specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: COMMITMENT TABLE]

[image: OCCURING TABLE]

Hello ,
I have two tables . COMMITMENT AND OCCURING . These are related with id and sub_id columns
My problem is that. ın comm table for first line item quantity is 89. In other table,occuring table,
ı have to find actual date which first line_item id quantitiy is satisfied.In my case , first line item id's actaul date : 19981217. In this date quantity is occured 105 in occuring table. but commitment quantity is 89. Difference is 16 is subtracted from second line_item id and will be calculated according to quantity.
How can I write query for this scenario. ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please add to your question a complete desired result, based on your sample data.  Please make sure to post tables as text (not images).